# Eliminar todos los usuarios como administradores locales

Tags: windows, batch, windows10, windows7

Quiero eliminar todos los usuarios locales que esta como administradores. tengo este pequeño bat pero no me funciono. solo se abre y cierra cmd pero no hace nada pero cuando lo copio y pego directamente en cmd si me funciona.
ayuda porfavor, esque tengo que hacerlo remoto para todos los usuarios de mi red de trabajo.

```
for /F "skip=6" %i in ('net localgroup Administrators') do net localgroup Administrators %i /delete
```

Comment: Esto es en Windows, cierto? En qué versión?

Comment: Lo utilicé en w7 pero me funcionó en w10 también y logré ejecutarlo remoto hacia todas las PC de la red

Comment: Procura usar etiquetas del os en el que trabajas este tipo de pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Encontre la el error en batch. y aqui les dejo la respuesta correcta.

```
for /F "skip=6" %%i in ('net.exe localgroup Administrators') do net.exe localgroup Administrators %%i /delete
```

esto lo pueden ejecutar remoto a varias ip utilizando PSEXEC